# (Python) Plotly Scatter - Specify Line Color with Integer Value

Tags: colors, plotly, scatter-plot, plotly-python

Plotly allows a user to specify a color of a marker scatter plot based on an integer value e.g.:

```
go.Scatter(x=x,
           y=y,
           mode='markers',
           marker=dict(color=i))
```

where i is an integer. However, if I want to specify the color of a line, neither of the following work:

```
go.Scatter(x=x,
           y=y,
           mode='lines',
           marker=dict(color=i))

go.Scatter(x=x,
           y=y,
           mode='lines',
           line=dict(color=i))
```

How do I specify the color of a Plotly line using an integer?

Answer (score 0):

In your case the `color` must be an array of numbers, not a number.

According to [Plotly documentation](https://plot.ly/python/reference/):

> Sets themarkercolor. It accepts either a specific color or an array of numbers that are mapped to the colorscale relative to the max and min values of the array or relative to `marker.cmin` and `marker.cmax` if set.

Example:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    y=[10, 11, 12, 13],
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(size=[40, 60, 80, 100],
                color=[0, 1, 2, 3])
))

fig.show()
```